# Free PCB program that can export to EAGLE or PROTEL

Tags: gratis, file-converter

There's a one and only local PCB making company that requires documentation from EAGLE or PROTEL. I would like to use a free program to make a PCB with multiple layers (top, bottom, text, etc.) just like in full EAGLE and then to convert it into the full EAGLE version one that can be sent.

Is there such a program?

Is the conversion even good and accurate?

Comment: So you need to use it commercially? I'm asking because there is [Eagle Free](http://www.cadsoft.de/download-eagle/eagle-freeware/)

Comment: I know for this one, but it's not multilayer. It only has top and bottom layer. I also can't have multiple in-software layers like text, paste, the green thing that covers the wires, etc..