# Free or low cost multilayer PCB design software

Tags: cad, pcb-design

I am trying to find a free/low cost [PCB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printed_circuit_board) design software that I can use for my projects (PCB = Printed Circuit Board; some prefer PWB, Printed Wiring Board). It needs to be able to support at least 8 layer boards, with no limitations (such as limited pin count/board size) and has to be able to export my design as a [Gerber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerber_format) file.

I've tried [ExpressPCB](http://www.expresspcb.com/), which I really like, but they only support up to 4 layers, where the 2 inner layers are only for power and ground. I've also tried [FreePCB](http://www.freepcb.com/), but you can't directly attach pads to copper areas, which I need to be able to do.

So basically I'm looking for something similar to [ExpressPCB](http://www.expresspcb.com/), but with support for more layers and a Gerber exporter. It would be nice if the software was free, but the most I'm willing to pay is $50. Any ideas?

Comment: What is PCB ...?

Comment: Printed Circuit Board, _(some prefer PWB, Printed Wiring Board)_.

Comment: Related and still unanswered: [Free PCB program than can export to Eagle or Protel](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/19793/free-pcb-program-that-can-export-to-eagle-or-protel)

Comment: @Jaca Can you add a link to PCBExpress? Do you actually mean [ExpressPCB](http://www.expresspcb.com/)?

Comment: @mguassa Oops, yeah I meant that. I edited in an link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[KiCad](http://kicad-pcb.org/) can do all that you require:

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform - Windows, Linux and OS X
- Up to **32** Copper Layers
- Footprint Editor
- Push & Shove Routing
- 3D Viewer
- Active User & Developer Communities
- Gerber Export
- Allows python scripting
- Lots of other goodies

[image: KiCad on OS-X]
[image: On Windows]
[image: 3D Viewer]

Comment: Yup, that's what I'm looking for. Thanks a bundle! I've heard of this, but nobody told me it could go up to 32 layers! That's 4 times more than I need. Perfect!